# Game Center - Reconnecting to game

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

In a multiplayer game set up by Game Center API, the game could disconnect if one of the players had to quit unexpectedly for a minute or more. This could happen for example when the player received a phone call. When that happens, and after the player resumed the game, is there a way to automatically reconnect him to the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to depend greatly on if you established the session via p2p Bluetooth/Wifi or over the Internet.

From the [GameCenter docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW24):

> Adding Players to an Existing Match
>   Sometimes you may already have a
>   match, and just want to add players to
>   it. For example, if your game requires
>   four players and a player gets
>   disconnected, you might want to offer
>   the option to find a replacement,
>   instead of aborting the match in
>   progress.
>
> To do this, you use code similar to
>   that found in Listing 5-7, but instead
>   of calling the
>   findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler:,
>   your application calls the
>   addPlayersToMatch:matchRequest:completionHandler:
>   method, adding the match to add the
>   players to as an additional parameter.

So basically, if you still have a match object, you can reuse it on either end.  It's up to you and your game to figure out what makes the most sense.

Comment: I saw this one as well, but the problem is that it will not reconnect - it will be a re-invite, and it will have to be initiated from the player still in the game. Or am I missing something?

Comment: does not necessarily have to be initiated by the player, your game logic that detects the disconnects can fire off a request as needed, why force them to tap something?

Comment: I agree - I don't want them to tap something. But detecting disconnect is not good enough for invitation - maybe the player didn't finish his call yet? Maybe I'm missing something. How would you handle that logic?

Comment: Does it need to be initiated from that end?  Why not re-connect from the end of the player that received that call, once he launches the app again?  Do you still have the old match at that point?

Comment: Most likely the other side will wait. Thats what I had in mind - but thought that perhaps there's a better way for it.

Comment: part of ios5 will be `- (BOOL)match:(GKMatch *)match shouldReinvitePlayer:(NSString *)playerID` but you'll need to wait for that

Comment: Yeah I saw that too... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done in **iOS4**. *HINT HINT*